# 2d collisions of perfectly elastic circles with mass

Tags: kinematics, momentum, energy-conservation, collision

My question is about 2 circles colliding. I can't describe it perfectly, which is part of the reason I'm stuck. Here is a picture.

[image: Here is a picture I made of the kind of collision I'm hoping to understand]

There are 2 circles. They both have an initial position, velocity, and mass. They collide.

**The collision**

Momentum is conserved, and since it is a vector, I can break it up into components. If I constrain this scenario further and say the collision is perfectly elastic, then KE is conserved. KE is not a vector, so I can't break that down any more. So I have 3 equations :

1. Px(before) = Px(after)
2. Py(before) = Py(after)
3. KE(before) = KE(after)

**The problem**

So the pickle is that I have 3 equations, but 4 unknown variables (the new velocities).

If it makes it easier, suppose mass is uniformly distributed over the area of a given circle.

**question-1a:**
Do I need to make additional assumptions in order to find a unique solution to this problem? If not, then

**question-1b:**
Have I misunderstood the application of the conservation of momentum for the case when the objects colliding are not point particles?

I can't help but think torque has something to do with it. When the circles strike, it feels like there would be a tendency for them to spin. Is that relevant?

Comment: What's the context of this problem?  Are you trying to create some sort of simulation for a game?  Or lack at the statistics of molecular collisions with a simplified model?  Because the problem seems like it might well be underspecified and an additional constraint needed to have a unique solution, in which case, we need to know the context of the problem to say which constraint makes sense.  The angle of collision in particular is likely going to be relevant.

Comment: It occurs to me that you perhaps could consider the potential energy before and after the collision.

Comment: If they are frictionless then no, here won't be any rotation and the forces during collision must act along the line joining the centers simply because there cannot be any force tangent to the circumference of the circles.

Comment: I'm just trying to develop some way of thinking about how collisions like this work. I suspect that there are more principles which contribute to to the circles' behavior during the collision which are not described at the basic level. I guess an analogy would be, if you drop a ball from some height, and you ignore wind resistance, it's straightforward. But if you don't ignore wind resistance, then all kinds of factors become important (the fluid, object shape etc). So there are more questions in that case. This is like that, I just don't know what other questions to ask.

Comment: @rcot, you might want to try to reword your post to make it more concise and to get to the point of where specifically you're stuck a bit sooner.  Currently, your post is a bit rambly, which makes it less likely you'll get good answers -- I learned that the hard way myself.  Also, when it comes to figuring out what specific questions to ask, that's something where ChatGPT and the like could actually be helpful.  It's pretty hit or miss with giving factual information, but pretty good at taking examples (like your frictionless ball example) and applying the same idea to other situations.

Comment: @MikaylaEckelCifrese Ok. I think it's a bit more clear now. It was rambly. I guess part of what's hard is when I look something like this up, there's a gazillion links on 2d collisions, but there's also a gazillion variations. And since I'm unfamiliar with the technical language, it makes it harder to narrow down my search. I'll try asking the robots too.

Comment: It is generally true that you can't completely "solve" a 2D collision using just energy and momentum conservation, for the reasons you've found;  you need an additional piece of information.  In your case the simplest assumption would be that the force the balls exert on each other lies along the line connecting their centers when they make contact.  I *think* this would give you enough information to find both final velocities.

Comment: Also, adding rotation will just make things more complicated, and I wouldn't do it in v1 of your code;  but in general this could be modeled by having the forces between the balls acting in directions *other* than along the line connecting them.

Comment: @rcot, I often find it helpful to take my original rambly post, feed it to chatGPT or the like and tell it to rewrite it to be more focused, concise,  or whatever.  I then modify what it gives me back until I'm happy with it.  It's super helpful in speeding up the process of writing both a _clear_ and _concise_ post, especially when I'm initially not quite sure myself what _specific_ question to ask.  Just make sure you clarify read what it outputs and modify as needed, since the exact output it gives is unlikely to be _exactly_ accurate to what you're trying to say.

Comment: @rcot, Good job rewriting your post to be clearer, more concise, and more readable.

Comment: @MikaylaEckelCifrese I appreciate the feedback. I was lucky that it was just my language and not my thinking that was too rambly. When I think of 2d collisions, this is pretty much the first thing that comes to mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that you are trying to count the degrees of freedom (DoF) and the number of equations. The answer to this is quite fun and subtle.

> So the pickle is that I have 3 equations, but 4 unknown variables (the new velocities).

I will come back to how you are correct, but you should be counting a lot more. Let us ignore the possibility of the circles rotating. Then you have the position of each of the two circles, two coördinates each, so that is already 4 variables. Their velocities make 4 variables too, so you actually have 8 DoF.

You know that there is a centre of mass. Conservation of (total) linear momentum (CoLM or Co$\vec p$) means that the centre of mass moves on a straight line with uniform velocity.

Before and after the collision, the relative momentum is also constant, which means that the relative motion is also made of straight lines. That is, the relative position is really equivalent to a time coördinate, just like the centre of mass is.

Taking the origin to be the event of the collision and using polar coördinates, then you can see that we have even more constants: The angles are constant before and after the collision, and the collision can only change the angle. The radius becomes basically the time coördinate.

If the energy is not conserved in the collision, i.e. only before and after the collision, then the relative momentum's magnitude can also change at the collision.

---

Let us come back to the 3 equations and 4 unknown variables. Really, these are all about the momenta, with energy being a constraint on the magnitude of the relative momentum. This leaves the *angle* of the relative momentum free to change in a collision, and it is precisely this that is correctly being shown as the missing equation.

Now, if you are dealing with this 2 circle problem, then the line of collision is itself a constraint: you can assert that the momentum transfer is only along this line of collision, and then that will fix the new angle. This obviously changes when you have rotations, because then the momentum transfer cannot only be along the line of collision.

> When the circles strike, it feels like there would be a tendency for them to spin. Is that relevant?

Yes, as mentioned above.

Comment: I think this answers my question. The 3 equations I had, they don't impose enough restrictions on the momentum being transferred. And I was confused bc there could be an infinite number of output velocities to satisfy the 3 equations. But if momentum transfer is restricted to being parallel to the LOC, then the x and y components of the output velocities can no longer vary independently. In fact, I was puzzling over a comment to my original question by @MichaelSeifert who suggested that if we make that assumption, a unique solution may be possible. I will work out the math first to make sure.

Comment: @rcot:  If I have time I'll sit down & work it out myself (I think it'd be an interesting calculation), but I've been wrapped up in new-student orientation activities here for most of this week.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I found a solution by incorporating the LOC constraint but I'm not sure if I did everything correctly. I may ask that as a separate question, as my principle inquiry here was centered on whether or not I had correctly acknowledged the nature of the problem (which I had not). I imagined circles A and B as transferring t (non-zero) units of vector n (the LOC vector scaled to have a magnitude of 1). The momentum side of it works for all t since A gets what B gives up and vise versa. But the KE side reduces to a quadratic for t, which gives the final momentums then velocities.

Comment: @rcot:  That all seems plausible!  You might consider leaving that as an answer on this question, rather than posting it as a new question.  ("Check-my-work" questions often get closed on this site, whereas an answer here can be refined and accepted.)

Answer (score 0):

It might add some value to the solution by showing how I've interpreted the math unfolding on the basis of the logic of the accepted answer.

I used the following variable convention because it made sense to me. There are 2 particles, `A` and `B`. Each has the following properties : `m` denotes mass, `{u,ux,uy}` are velocity before, `{g,gx,gy}` are momentum before, `{v,vx,vy}` are velocity after, `{p,px,py}` are momentum after

So `Aux` would be the velocity of A in the x direction before the collision. And so on.

by invoking the conservation of momentum we can write :

```
Ag + Bg = Ap = Bp
```

and by asserting that momentum is exchanged along the line of collision, AND what is gained/lost by A is lost/gained by B, AND where n is the vector representing the line of collision, scaled to have a magnitude of 1, we can write :

```
Ap = Ag + t*n, where t !== 0

Bp = Bg - t*n, where t !== 0
```

and if we assert that this is a perfectly elastic collision, then we can constrain things further with KE conversion, where we can write :

```
KE = 0.5*Am*(Aux**2+Auy**2) + 0.5*Bm*(Bux**2+Buy**2)
   = 0.5*Am*(Avx**2+Avy**2) + 0.5*Bm*(Bvx**2+Bvy**2)
```

and all this is enough because we can rewrite the velocities after the collision like this

```
Avx = (Am*Aux + t*nx)/Am
Avy = (Am*Auy + t*ny)/Am
Bvx = (Bm*Bux - t*nx)/Bm
Bvy = (Bm*Buy - t*ny)/Bm
```

and we can sub these into our equation for KE conservation

```
KE = 0.5*Am*[ Aux^2 + Auy^2 ]
   + 0.5*Bm*[ Bux^2 + Buy^2 ]
   = 0.5*Am*[ ((Am*Aux + t*nx)/Am)^2 + ((Am*Auy + t*ny)/Am)^2 ]
   + 0.5*Bm*[ ((Bm*Bux + t*nx)/Bm)^2 + ((Bm*Buy + t*ny)/Bm)^2 ]
```

it only looks ugly for a second. it reduces to quadratic for t with the following specs

```
a = (1/Am+1/Bm)*(nx^2+ny^2)
b = 2*((Aux-Bux)*nx + (Auy-Buy)*ny)
c = 0
```

noting that `c = 0`, and that `t=0` is a violation of the condition that `t !== 0`

```
t = (-b +- (b^2-4ac)**0.5) / (2a)
  = -2b / (2a)
  = -b/a
```

and once we have that we know how much momentum was traded. and we can use that to figure out the final velocities of A and B. Like so :

```
Av = [ (Am*Aux+t*nx)/Am // (Am*Auy+t*ny)/Am ]
Bv = [ (Bm*Bux-t*nx)/Bm // (Bm*Buy-t*ny)/Bm ]
```

I used this to calculate the new velocities of colliding circles in an animation and it appears to be behaving as I'd expect.

This response is mostly an informal test of a new set of criteria for the collision based on the underlying logic of the accepted answer. That, if in addition to conservation of momentum and conservation of kinetic energy, if I assume momentum is transferred from A to B along the line of collision, then the system resolves to a unique solution.